# About copy all data and the lasts register in table, with different names, but equal structure

Tags: sql

goodnight,

I have a table of over 400 million records.

and because it is definitely and with little possibility to perform an online DDL without impacting the environment, I would like to know how I can copy the data, respecting the last record of the table, example max(id) (in the source table) and include the remaining missing data controlling in the destination table.

observation

I already created the destination table with auto increment taking into account about 100 numbers ahead because I know that the table is well used.
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1373246706

Comment: So what is your question exactly? Is it how to bulk copy? How to make an insert performant? How to make sure you do not use different ids when copying? Also what have you tried and why is it not working? Finally if this is for a different environment or database you could also create a DB backup of the source, restore that and do the copy from that restore.

Comment: Ola igor.

vamos la, 

copiar em massa eu sei , insert into  + as ( select ......)

para tanto no Mysql nao tem o BCP do SQLSERVER.
e a minha necessidade apos fazer a primeira carga é fazer a carga com os poucos dados restantes, respeitando o max(id) + 1 do auto increment da tabela destino

Comment: Hello igor. come on, mass copy I know, insert into + as (select ......) for both Mysql doesn't have the BCP of SQLSERVER. and my need after doing the first load is to load with the few remaining data, respecting the max(id) + 1 of the destination table's auto increment